# Split a string into chunks of the same length

Tags: c#, strings

Inspired by this question in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)

> Is there an easy way in .NET to split a string into an array by pulling chunks of the text in. I.e. I have an 18 character string I would like in 3 6-character pieces.

I thought that ain't be that hard. I would like to get any thoughts and improvements you can think of.

```
public static string[] Split(this string value, int desiredLength, bool strict = false)
{

    EnsureValid(value, desiredLength, strict);

    if (value.Length == 0) { return new string[0]; }

    int numberOfItems = value.Length / desiredLength;

    int remaining = (value.Length > numberOfItems * desiredLength) ? 1 : 0;

    IList<string> splitted = new List<string>(numberOfItems + remaining);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
    {
        splitted.Add(value.Substring(i * desiredLength, desiredLength));
    }

    if (remaining != 0)
    {
        splitted.Add(value.Substring(numberOfItems * desiredLength));
    }

    return splitted.ToArray();
}

private static void EnsureValid(string value, int desiredLength, bool strict)
{
    if (value == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)); }

    if (value.Length == 0 && desiredLength != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The passed {nameof(value)} may not be empty if the {nameof(desiredLength)} <> 0");
    }

    if (value.Length != 0 && desiredLength < 1) { throw new ArgumentException($"The value of {nameof(desiredLength)} needs to be > 0"); }

    if (strict && (value.Length % desiredLength != 0))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The passed {nameof(value)}'s length can't be split by the {nameof(desiredLength)}");
    }
}
```

I know the tests aren't complete and the naming could be better, like the missing of a test if the passed in `value == null`, but here they are for review as well

```
[TestMethod()]
public void SplitTest()
{
    string input = "123456";
    string[] expected = new string[] { "123", "456" };
    string[] actual = input.Split(3);

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod()]
public void SplitTestNotEqual()
{
    string input = "12345";
    string[] expected = new string[] { "123", "45" };
    string[] actual = input.Split(3);

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod()]
[ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void SplitTestDesiredlengthIsZero()
{
    string input = "12345";
    string[] actual = input.Split(0);
}

[TestMethod()]
public void SplitTestDesiredlengthIsZeroWithEmptyString()
{
    string input = "";
    string[] expected = new string[0];
    string[] actual = input.Split(0);

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod()][ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
public void SplitTestWillThrowBecauseOfStrict()
{
    string input = "12345";
    string[] actual = input.Split(3,true);
}
```

Comment: I wanted to do the same a few years ago, if any help on how to simplify it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632078/split-string-in-512-char-chunks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Algorithm can't be improved (or at least I see no reason to do it, ignoring a minor micro-optimization about `List<string>` which usage, however, helps to keep code much more readable) and code is pretty clear, however:

- You're returning `string[]` but consumers may not need it. `List.ToArray()` won't simply return internal array (because its `capacity != size`). It implies you will make another (relatively expansive) copy. I'd simply return `IEnumerable<string>`: if consumer needs an array it can call `ToArray()` LINQ extension method (which will/may check for underlying implementation), it he doesn't need an array then you saved an `Array.Copy()`.
- You're partitioning over `Char` but `String` is UTF-16 encoded then you may produce *broken* strings in, at least, three cases:

  1. **One character is encoded with more than one code unit**. Unicode code point for that character is encoded as two UTF-16 code units, each code unit may end up in two different slices (and both strings will be *invalid*).
  2. **One character is composed by more than one code point**. You're dealing with a character made by two separate Unicode code points (for example Han character ).
  3. **One character has combining characters or modifiers**. This is more common than you may think: for example Unicode combining character like *U+0300 COMBINING GRAVE ACCENT* used to *build* <kbd>à</kbd> and Unicode *modifiers* such as *U+02BC MODIFIER LETTER APOSTROPHE*.
- Definition of *character* for a programming language and for a human being are pretty different, for example in <del>Czech</del> Slovak (thanks svick to correct me about this) *dž* is a single character however it's made by 2/3 Unicode code points which are in this case also 2/3 UTF-16 code units then `"dž".Length > 1`. More about this and other *cultural issues* on [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27229590/1207195).
- Ligatures exist. Assuming one ligature is one code point (and also assuming it's encoded as one code unit) then you will treat it as a single *glyph* however it represents two *characters*. What to do in this case? In general definition of *character* may be pretty vague because it has a different *meaning* according to discipline where this word is used. You can't (probably) handle everything correctly but you should set some constraints and document code behavior.

To address all these issues (also third point if current culture is correctly set but not last one) I'd use:

<del>string[] characters = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(value).ToArray();</del>

And I'd perform subsequent processing over `characters` array instead of `value`. Note that this may lead to strings made of **different length but with the same number of characters**. For example (when performance are not an issue):

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string value, int desiredLength)
{
    var characters = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(value);
    while (characters.MoveNext())
        yield return String.Concat(Take(characters, desiredLength));
}

private static IEnumerable<string> Take(TextElementEnumerator enumerator, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        yield return (string)enumerator.Current;

        if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
            yield break;
    }
}
```

To do not reinvent the wheel you may just create your own `AsEnumerable()` extension method to *walk through* an existing enumerator:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AsEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerator enumerator)
{
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        yield return (T)enumerator.Current;
}
```

Your code will be then simplified to:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string value, int desiredLength)
{
    var characters = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(value);
    do
    {
        yield return String.Concat(characters.AsEnumerable<string>().Take(desiredLength));
    } while (characters.MoveNext());
}
```

If you don't need `string[]` return type you may live with `IEnumerable<string>` and use LINQ `ToArray()` when/if required (code is slightly simplified for demonstrative purposes, in real world you will need some error checking).

If you're processing US ASCII text and you won't need to partition *horse d'œvre* then you can simply ignore these issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The unicode part is quite enlightened. Do you maybe have some link(s) to read more about these kind of problems ?

Comment: I wrote little bit about this on a Stack Overflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27229590/1207195 but it's far to be complete (and should be improved a lot). It's a community wiki then feel free to add/edit/fix whatever you want.

Comment: Some clarifications from a Czech: *dž* is not a character in Czech (though [it seems to be a character in Slovak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%C5%BE)). And it's written using two code points (d + ž), unless you use the aforementioned combining characters.

Comment: @svick thanks to point this out, I fixed example. Yes, I don't have ž on my keyboard then for me it was (wrongly) always 3 code points.

Comment: +1 - it's always nice to see someone else commenting about unicode. For the record, I always use the canonical form of e acute as my example: `var eAcute = "e\u0301"; // é ` because it's a letter that is used in english, e.g. café, so more readily grokkable (for english speakers).

Comment: @RobH I agree, I don't do it just because I got it on my keyboard but if those duplicates were dropped in favor of combining characters only then our life would be easier. I'm not sure (Heslacher may help us about this) but with German keyboards they may have both forms.

Answer (score 5):

There are only two things I can suggest:

1. You don't need to create a `List<string>` first and then copy it to an array via `ToArray()` extension method. You know an exact number of elements in the output, so it should be just an array `string[]`.
2. Since there are several methods named `Split` in the `String` class, it may be a little confusing. Consider to rename your method.

Answer (score 4):

Although [@AdrianoRepetti](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/13424/adriano-repetti)'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111925/29371) is addressing some very important points, the suggested  code

> ```
> string[] characters = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(value).ToArray();
> ```

just didn't happen to exists. Nevertheless his answer gave me a headstart for an answer to my question.

So I digged a little bit into the [`StringInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.stringinfo%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) class and discovered that there lives a very handy method, namely the [`SubstringByTextElements()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6skbbth0%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method which seems to serve my purpose well.

In addition the `LengthInTextElements` property needs to replace the calls to the `string.Length` property to make the whole thing work.

---

By reading [@Dmitri](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/39186/dmitry)'s [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111928/29371) I realized that he is right about

> You know an exact number of elements in the output, so it should be just an array string[].

Unfortunately I can't agree about the naming, because just because the string class already has a `Split()` method I want to provide this as an overloaded one.

---

So after applying the mentioned points the methods will look like so

```
public static string[] Split(this string value, int desiredLength, bool strict = false)
{

    EnsureValid(value, desiredLength, strict);

    var stringInfo = new StringInfo(value);

    int currentLength = stringInfo.LengthInTextElements;
    if (currentLength == 0) { return new string[0]; }

    int numberOfItems = currentLength / desiredLength;

    int remaining = (currentLength > numberOfItems * desiredLength) ? 1 : 0;

    var chunks = new string[numberOfItems + remaining];

    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
    {
        chunks[i] = stringInfo.SubstringByTextElements(i * desiredLength, desiredLength);
    }

    if (remaining != 0)
    {
        chunks[numberOfItems] = stringInfo.SubstringByTextElements(numberOfItems * desiredLength);
    }

    return chunks;
}
private static void EnsureValid(string value, int desiredLength, bool strict)
{
    if (value == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)); }

    if (value.Length == 0 && desiredLength != 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The passed {nameof(value)} may not be empty if the {nameof(desiredLength)} <> 0");
    }

    var info = new StringInfo(value);
    int valueLength = info.LengthInTextElements;

    if (valueLength != 0 && desiredLength < 1) { throw new ArgumentException($"The value of {nameof(desiredLength)} needs to be > 0"); }

    if (strict && (valueLength % desiredLength != 0))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException($"The passed {nameof(value)}'s length can't be split by the {nameof(desiredLength)}");
    }
}
```

which aren't only passing the former tests, but also this new tests

```
[TestMethod()]
public void SplitTestUnicodeVariant()
{
    string input = "a";
    string[] expected = new string[] { "", "a", "", "" };
    string[] actual = input.Split(2);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
[TestMethod()]
public void SplitTestUnicodeVariant1()
{
    string input = "džaé";
    string[] expected = new string[] { "dž", "a", "é" };
    string[] actual = input.Split(3);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
[TestMethod()]
public void SplitTestUnicodeVariant2()
{
    string input = "éée\u0301éé";
    string[] expected = new string[] { "éé", "e\u0301é", "é" };
    string[] actual = input.Split(2);
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti the `GetTextElementEnumerator()` method exists, but there is no way to call `ToArray()` on the result because the result is a `TextElementEnumerator` on which one would need to call `GetTextElement()` prior to calling `ToArray()`.

Comment: The unicode approach is overkill for ANSI encoded strings. I suggest to make 2 seperate implementations, a fast naive one for ANSI (most of time you'll need this one), and another one that supports Unicode.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few things that popped in my mind seeing this:

**Generalization**

The method can be used to split any enumerable/collection/array, but this is just a minor point.

**`EnsureValid`**

IMO this method does a little too much. It: checks if the parameters are valid (`desiredLength != 0`, which I think should also be `desiredLength > 0` given the context) and also takes action to prevent the application from going on (throws exceptions, in this case). I'd change it into something like the following:

```
private static bool IsValid(string value, int desiredLength, bool strict)
{
    return value != null
        && !(value.Length == 0 && desiredLength != 0)
        && !(value.Length != 0 && desiredLength < 1)
        && !(strict && (value.Length % desiredLength != 0));
}
```

and let the management of special cases to the caller. In this way, the first line of the `Split` method becomes something like the following:

```
public static string[] Split(this string value, int desiredLength, bool strict = false)
{
    if(!IsValid(value, desiredLength, strict))
    {
        // manage the non valid case here
    }

    // other logic
}
```

**`Split` method**

In the current case, for `string`s I mean, the method seems good. In case you consider changing it for the general case, I'd suggest the following logic:

```
public static T[] Split<T>(this T[] value, int desiredLength, bool strict = false)
{
    if(!IsValid(value, desiredLength, strict))
    {
        // manage invalid case
    }

    var numberOfItems = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)value.Length / (double)desiredLength);
    var result = new T[numberOfItems];
    var chunkItems = new List<T>();

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++)
    {
        int chunkFirstIndex = i * desiredLength;

        for(int j = 0, currentIndex = chunkFirstIndex; 
            j < desiredLength && currentIndex < value.Length; 
            j++, currentIndex++)
        {
            chunkItems.Add(value[currentIndex]);
        }

        result[i] = chunkItems.ToArray();
        chunkItems.Clear();
    }

    return result;
}
```

Other than these things, everything else looks fine.

P.S: The code I wrote is not tested, it's there just to better explain the idea.

Comment: I don't agree with the `IsValid()` method. The `EnsureValid()` method does exactly what it should by ensuring that the passed arguments are valid. If they aren't valid the program flow is interupted by an exception. It can be seen like some `Assert.()` method.

Comment: @Heslacher I see your point. I saw it more like an `Assert.IsTrue(IsValid())`

Answer (score 2):

I personally advise against designing a library function with the name of an existing framework function, but with a fundamentally different functionality. That only leads to confusion. I would call the function `Crop` because, well, it crops a string in evenly sized pieces.

Also implementing the functionality using an enumerator is ill advised, because we can calculate the exact amount of memory to allocate. Furthermore the function is so very light, that you'd be hard pressed to gain any advantage from an enumerator, even, if you only need the first element cropped. Since the object instantiation probably takes about the same time we need to finish, for smaller strings.

Below is my implementation for a [tool library](https://github.com/ProphetLamb-Organistion/Groundbeef/blob/master/src/Text/StringHelper.cs#L827):

- The implementation validates & counts the Unicode symbols in the string.
- Iterates over all chars in one Unicode symbol at a time, and
- `memcpy`s the range of the string to the output array. This is done in the string `ctor(char*,int,int)` with `Buffer.Memmove` after the string allocation.
- Counting the Unicode symbols in the validated string is done branchlessly.
- !Warning: Only supports Unicode upto including version 4.1
- !Important: When compiling with NET 5 or with [this PR](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/44609) merged, my implementation of counting chars comprising a Unicode rune/symbol should be dropped in favor of `StringInfo.GetNextTextElementLength`

```csharp
[Pure]
public static string[] Crop(this ReadOnlySpan<char> self, int chunkLength, bool strict)
{
    if (strict && self.Length % chunkLength != 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(chunkLength));
    return Crop(self, chunkLength);
}

[Pure]
public static unsafe string[] Crop(this ReadOnlySpan<char> self, int chunkLength)
{
    int symbolCount = CountTextSymbols(self);
    if (symbolCount == 0)
    {
        if (chunkLength == 0)
            return new string[0];
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(self));
    }
    if (chunkLength > symbolCount || chunkLength <= 0)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(chunkLength));
    if (symbolCount == chunkLength)
        return new []{ self.ToString() };

    string[] output = new string[(symbolCount - 1) / chunkLength + 1];
    fixed (char* ptr = &MemoryMarshal.GetReference(self))
    {
        if (symbolCount == self.Length)
        {
            CropAscii(ptr, symbolCount, chunkLength, output);
        }
        else
        {
            CropUnicode(ptr, symbolCount, chunkLength, output);   
        }
    }
    return output;
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static unsafe void CropAscii(char* source, int symbolCount, int chunkLength, string[] output)
{
    int outIndex = 0;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i + chunkLength <= symbolCount; i += chunkLength)
    {
        output[outIndex++] = new string(source, i, chunkLength);
    }

    if (symbolCount != i)
    {
        output[outIndex] = new string(source, i, symbolCount - i);
    }
}

[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static unsafe void CropUnicode(char* source, int symbolCount, int chunkLength, string[] output)
{
    int outIndex = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int blockCharCount;
    do
    {
        blockCharCount = 0;
        int increment;
        for (int blockSymbols = 0; i < symbolCount && blockSymbols < chunkLength; i++, blockSymbols++, blockCharCount += increment)
        {
            increment = UnicodeSymbolCharLength(source + blockCharCount);
        }

        output[outIndex++] = new string(source, 0, blockCharCount);
        source += blockCharCount;
    } while (i < symbolCount);

    if (symbolCount != i)
    {
        source -= blockCharCount;
        blockCharCount = 0;
        while (*(source + blockCharCount) != 0)
            blockCharCount++;
        output[outIndex] = new string(source, 0, blockCharCount);
    }
}

public static int CountTextSymbols(this ReadOnlySpan<char> self) => CountTextSymbols(self, true);

public static int CountTextSymbols(this string? self, bool throwOnIllegalSymbol) => CountTextSymbols(self.AsSpan(), throwOnIllegalSymbol);

public static unsafe int CountTextSymbols(this ReadOnlySpan<char> self, bool throwOnIllegalSymbol)
{
    if (self.IsEmpty)
        return 0;
    int length;
    fixed (char* inPtr = &MemoryMarshal.GetReference(self))
    {
        length = CountValidTextSymbols(inPtr, self.Length);
    }

    if (length > 0)
        return length;

    length = ~length;
    if (throwOnIllegalSymbol)
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format(ExceptionResource.UNICODE_ILLEGAL_SYMBOL, length), nameof(self));
    return length;
}

[Pure]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static unsafe int CountValidTextSymbols(char* c, int remainingChars)
{
    int increment;
    int length = 0;
    do
    {
        increment = ValidateUnicodeSymbol(c);
        if (increment > 0)
        {
            c += increment;
            length++;
        }
    } while (increment > 0);

    if (increment < 0)
    {
        return ~length;
    }

    return length;
}

/// <summary>Returns the number of 2byte characters that compose the next symbol. If the symbol is illegal returns the complement of the number of corrupted 2byte characters.</summary>
[Pure]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static unsafe int ValidateUnicodeSymbol(char* c)
{
    // Modified from source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27084836/6401643

    uint ch = *c;
    // Null terminator -> return zero
    if (ch == 0)
        return 0;

    if (ch < 0xD800) // Char is up to first high surrogate
    {
        uint chLow = *(c + 1);

        if (chLow > 0x02F0 && chLow < 0x0370)
        {
            // Found combining -> check for 1byte in hi
            if (ch == 0)
            {
                return ~1;
            }

            if ((ch & 0xFF00) == 0)
            {
                // Found pair
                return 2;
            }
        }

        // Did not find pair, preserve combining character.
        return 1;
    }

    
    if (ch <= 0xDBFF)
    {
        uint chLow = *(c + 1);

        // Found high surrogate -> check surrogate pair
        if (chLow == 0)
        {
            // Fast char is high surrogate, so it is missing its pair
            return ~1;
        }

        if (!(chLow >= 0xDC00 && chLow <= 0xDFFF))
        {
            // Did not find a low surrogate after the high surrogate
            return ~1;
        }

        // Convert to UTF32 - like in Char.ConvertToUtf32(highSurrogate, lowSurrogate)
        ch = ((ch - 0xD800) << 10) + (chLow - 0xDC00) + 0x10000;
        if ((ch & 0xFFFE) == 0xFFFE) // Other non-char found
            return ~2;
        // Found a good surrogate pair
        return 2;
    }

    if (ch <= 0xDFFF) // Unexpected low surrogate
        return ~1;

    if (ch >= 0xFDD0 && ch <= 0xFDEF) // Non-chars are considered invalid by System.Text.Encoding.GetBytes() and String.Normalize()
        return ~1;

    if ((ch & 0xFFFE) == 0xFFFE) // Other non-char found
        return ~1;

    return 1;
}

/// <summary>
/// !Warning: Does not validate the symbol
/// !Warning: Assumes that the pointer does not point to the null terminator.
/// Returns the number of 2byte characters that compose the next symbol.
/// </summary>
[Pure]
[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
private static unsafe int UnicodeSymbolCharLength(char* c)
{
    // We can always check c and c + 1 (four bytes total) because of the null terminator.
    uint w32C = *(uint*)c;
    // Check whether we have a utf32 character
    bool isTwoChars = (w32C & 0xFC00FC00) == 0xDC00D800;
    // Check whether we have a 1byte character in lo and a combining 2byte character in hi
    isTwoChars |= ((w32C >> 16) > 0x02F0) & ((w32C >> 16) < 0x0370);
    return 1 + *(byte*)(&isTwoChars); // Casting bool to byte is 0 when false, 1 when true;
}
```