# Partitioning a string into chunks

Tags: c#, rags-to-riches

Inspired by this question: [Split a string into chunks of the same length](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111919/split-a-string-into-chunks-of-the-same-length)

The code is designed to work on text elements rather than chars to avoid unicode problems.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Partition(this string value, int chunkSize)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        }
        if (chunkSize < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(chunkSize));
        }
        var sb = new StringBuilder(chunkSize);
        var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(value);
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            sb.Append(enumerator.GetTextElement());
            for (var i = 0; i < chunkSize - 1; i++)
            {
                if (!enumerator.MoveNext())
                {
                    break;
                }
                sb.Append(enumerator.GetTextElement());
            }
            yield return sb.ToString();
            sb.Length = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

And a couple of unit tests

```
[TestMethod]
public void Partition_SplittingAnAsciiString_ShouldSplitTheStringIntoTheRequiredChunkSize()
{
    string input = "123456";
    string[] expected = { "123", "456" };
    string[] actual = input.Partition(3).ToArray();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Partition_SplittingAPartiallyDecomposedString_ShouldSplitTheStringIntoTheRequiredChunkSize()
{
    string input = "éée\u0301";
    string[] expected = { "é", "é", "e\u0301" };
    string[] actual = input.Partition(1).ToArray();

    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

I usually use Machine Specifications for unit tests so any tips on writing MSTest unit tests would be great especially naming conventions!

The method feels slightly too long to me but I couldn't see a nice way of splitting it up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice and clean implementation. I tested this with the tests (the new ones) of my implementation and they all passed (skipping the tests with chunkSize == 0).

The code could be sligthly more readable by having some vertical space to group related code, for instance after validating the input.

You could improve this a little bit by just having this

```
if (chunkSize == 1)
{
    yield return value;
    yield break;
}
```

after the validation, in this way you wouldn't need to create a `StringBuilder` nor having the `enumerator`.

---

A slightly different approach could be to remove the `for` loop. It makes the intent more clear (IMO) and removes the need to double check return value of `enumerator.MoveNext()`.

Unfortunately this makes the code 2 lines (3 with the vertical spacing) longer

```
        var sb = new StringBuilder(chunkSize);
        var enumerator = StringInfo.GetTextElementEnumerator(value);
        var counter = 0;
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            counter++;
            sb.Append(enumerator.GetTextElement());
            if (counter == chunkSize)
            {
                yield return sb.ToString();

                sb.Length = 0;
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        if (counter > 0)
        {
            yield return sb.ToString();
        }
```

---

Regarding naming of unit tests, I usually (not in the posted question of mine) use the pattern

UnitOfWork_StateUnderTest_ExpectedBehavior

like shown in the accepted answer over here: [unit test naming best practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155436/unit-test-naming-best-practices)

Comment: Also, Prefer using yield break over return on lazy enumerables. The reason for this is that a simple return statement on a lazy method body doesn't compile but the yield break will.

Comment: I would also be expecting using `enumerator.Current` instead of `enumerator.GetTextElement()` unless there is a very compelling reason to not do it

Answer (score 1):

I think this type of problems are better solved with LINQ since there is little to no control-flow that can go wrong.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<string> Partition(this string value, int chunkSize)
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value));
        }

        if (chunkSize < 1)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(chunkSize));
        }

        var stringInfo = new StringInfo(value);

        return Enumerable.Range(0, stringInfo.LengthInTextElements)
            .GroupBy(index => index / chunkSize)
            .Select(@group => stringInfo.SubstringByTextElements(@group.First(), @group.Count()));          
     }      
 }
```