# Converting strings to PascalCase

Tags: c#, strings, converting

I have a method which I use on occasion to convert strings (like `enum` and property names) to `PascalCase` for display.

It's fairly simple, so there's *probably* not much to comment on, but as usual I appreciate any advice on improving it.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a string of dash-separated, or underscore-separated words to a PascalCase string.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="s">The string to convert.</param>
/// <returns>The resulting PascalCase string.</returns>
public static string ToPascalCase(this string s)
{
    string[] words = s.Split(new char[2] { '-', '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(words.Sum(x => x.Length));

    foreach (string word in words)
    {
        sb.Append(word[0].ToString().ToUpper() + word.Substring(1));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Feel free to use it if you like, as per my usual regards.

Comment: Curious observation: you force the first character of a word to be uppercase but don't force subsequent characters to be lowercase.  So "FOO-BAR" will return "FOOBAR" and not "FooBar".

Comment: @RickDavin Very good point, I'll have to make that correction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doing string concatenation to pass a string argument to the `Append ()` method of the `StringBuilder` is the wrong way. Use instead multiple calls to prevent unneccessary creation of string objects. There are overloads for the different types so you could call it once for the starting uppercase `char` and another which takes the remaining `string`.

If by any chance there are some localized strings involved where the unicode textlength isn't `1` for a character, you won't get the expected results. See the accepted answer and mine [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/111919/split-a-string-into-chunks-of-the-same-length)

While initializing a `StringBuilder` with a capacity is the way to go, I would like to suggest to just use the `Length` of the passed string `s`.

The passed in `string s` should be checked against `null` and if it is `null` throw an `ArgumentNullException` which would be more correct than the `NullReferenceException` you would get without the check.

Answer (score 13):

I think you should use `Concat` instead of `StringBuilder`:

```
public static string ToPascalCase(this string s)
{
    var words = s.Split(new[] { '-', '_' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                 .Select(word => word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + 
                                 word.Substring(1).ToLower());

    var result = String.Concat(words);
    return result;
}
```

This solution should not be as fast as manually looping through the original string, but I think it is much easier to read and follow. Unless you do those convertions like 1000000 times per second, you should not complicate things.

Comment: I thought source code in an amswer on codereview would be more readable than this :) Formatting it to fit to the readable area at least would be nice.

Comment: @OguzOzgul fair enough.

Comment: This is readable, good! Instead of string.Join with string.Empty, use string.Concat. Also do not mix String and string. I believe best practice is to use string in C#.

Comment: Good idea about `Concat`! I use `String`, when I access static members and `string` when declaring variables. I cant really explain why, but I am used to it.

Answer (score 8):

Compared to the `String`, `StringBuilder` is mutable. Meaning you don't really need to `Append` multiple times, you could just replace the characters from the original `string`:

```
//that's just for the test
string s = "-asd_asd_asd-asd-";

if(s.Length == 0)
{
    return s;
}

var sb = new StringBuilder(s.ToLowerInvariant());
sb[0] = Char.ToUpper(sb[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < sb.Length; i++)
{
    if (sb[i] == '_' || sb[i] == '-')
    {
        sb.Remove(i, 1);
        if (i != sb.Length)
        {
            sb[i] = Char.ToUpper(sb[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this technique you don't need to spit the string and do substrings. Obviously, there're more `if` involved :p But I think it would be faster.

Answer (score 7):

If performance is your main concern, you might want to loop through the string just once, using a for loop, and appending substrings to the StringBuilder.

It will make your code a little longer and mebe a little harder to read.

Here is an example of what it might look like.

```
public static string ToPascalCase(this string s)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.Length);
    int a = 1, b = 1;
    bool toUpper = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        switch (s[i])
        {
            case '-':
            case '_':
                if (a != b)
                {
                    sb.Append(s.Substring(a, b - a));
                }
                a = b = i + 2;
                toUpper = true;
                break;

            default:
                if (toUpper)
                {
                    sb.Append(char.ToUpper(s[i]));
                    toUpper = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    b++;
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    if (a != b)
    {
        sb.Append(s.Substring(a, b - a));
    }

    return sb.ToString();
}
```

But as far as your code goes, it's short, readable, and unless you are performing millions of these all the time, I think your version is more than adequate.

Answer (score 5):

This is my take on it, the akward part is that you need to convert the string to lower case before calling ToTitleCase because if all letters in a word are uppercase it will remain uppercased as it is identified as an acronym and preserved by the ToTitleCase implementation.

```
public static string ToPascalCase(this string text)
{
    return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.TextInfo
        .ToTitleCase(text.ToLowerInvariant())
        .Replace("-", "")
        .Replace("_", "");
}
```

Comment: I have thought about `ToTitleCase()` as well, but if you consider that each char which follows any non alphanumeric character will be titlecased, this won't produce the same result. Nevertheless +1 at least for using `ToLowerInvariant()`

Answer (score 2):

This version has got more readability using [`RegexReplace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static string ToPascalCase(this string text)
{
    const string pattern = @"(-|_)\w{1}|^\w";
    return Regex.Replace(text, pattern, match => match.Value.Replace("-", string.Empty).Replace("_", string.Empty).ToUpper());
}
```

Comment: "Has got more readability using Regex" is oxymoron. :)

Comment: Apart from Regex pattern, I feel the code is bit cleaner.

Comment: Its just that in my experience most people do not understand regex syntax off the top of their heads. I know I don't, I have to google it every time. :) Thats why I am sceptical about `Regex` solution being "more readable". I might be wrong though.

Comment: You have missed the possbility that there are two _'s in a row and you might want to use groups instead of the replaces.  Also the \w will match _'s so that might cause some wierd behaviour.

`const string pattern = @"(?<fc>[^\W_])|[-_]+(?<fc>[^\W_]{0,1})";
            Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(text, pattern, m => m.Groups["fc"].Value.ToUpper()));`