# Wrapping single line string to multiple lines with specific length

Tags: c#, algorithm, strings, formatting

**Problem**

A single line should be separated by `Environment.NewLine` so that each row has a length of `columns` (expect for the last one that may be shorter).

Below is my solution:

```
    public static string Wrap(this string singleLineString, int columns)
    {
        if (singleLineString == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("singleLineString");
        if (columns < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("'columns' must be greater than 0.");

        var rows = Math.Ceiling((double)singleLineString.Length/columns);
        if (rows < 2) return singleLineString;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0) sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
            var index = i*columns;
            var length = Math.Min(columns, singleLineString.Length - index);
            var line = singleLineString.Substring(index, length);
            sb.Append(line);
        }

        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

Even if the problem is really simple, there are lots of thinkable approaches to solve it. Is there simpler / more elegant solution than the one above?

Comment: Main problem I see here is encoding. I won't repeat the full discussion here, just see [Split a string into chunks of the same length](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/111919/13424) (where you will also see another possible implementation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you shouldn't build a new string there because it's a new responsibility. The method should only split the text and return its parts with the specified length.

The user should decide what to do with the results next. Maybe he does not want to use the `Environment.NewLine` but some other *new-line*?

I prefer it to be a split-only method:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string text, int partLength)
{
    if (text == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException("singleLineString"); }

    if (partLength < 1) { throw new ArgumentException("'columns' must be greater than 0."); }

    var partCount = Math.Ceiling((double)text.Length / partLength);
    if (partCount < 2)
    {
        yield return text;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < partCount; i++)
    {
        var index = i * partLength;
        var lengthLeft = Math.Min(partLength, text.Length - index);
        var line = text.Substring(index, lengthLeft);
        yield return line;
    }
}
```

I need to complain about the missing `{}` but I guess you probably know that ;-)

The names of the variables could also be a little bit clearer.

Technically you don't need this `if`:

> ```
>     if (partCount < 2)
>     {
>         yield return text;
>     }
> ```

The result will be the same with out it because the `for` would execute only once .

Comment: A possible alternative implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1450797/592182

Comment: @forsvarir I was thinking about something like this too but I was too lazy to actually write it :-]

Comment: @t3chb0t: indeed, that is more flexible - thanks! I added another method `Split` that contains the main logic. :) You say 'missing', I would say 'needless'.. but that is another discussion ;)

Comment: @forsvarir: The code of the accepted answer didn't work, but the second code fragment of the answer below did :) - thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Considering the answer from t3chb0t and forsvarir's suggestion for the alternative implementation, I came up with the following solution:

```
    public static string Wrap(this string singleLineString, int columns)
        => string.Join(Environment.NewLine, singleLineString.Split(columns));

    public static IEnumerable<string> Split(this string str, int chunkSize)
    {
        if (str == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("str");
        if (chunkSize < 1)
            throw new ArgumentException("'chunkSize' must be greater than 0.");

        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i += chunkSize)
            yield return str.Substring(i, Math.Min(chunkSize, str.Length - i));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Since LINQ can do pretty much anything, except for maybe flying a spaceship... It can definitely split a line into columns:

```
public static string Wrap(this string singleLineString, int columns)
{
    if (singleLineString == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("singleLineString");
    if (columns < 1)
        throw new ArgumentException("'columns' must be greater than 0.");

    var rows = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)singleLineString.Length / columns);
    if (rows < 2) return singleLineString;

    return String.Join(
      Environment.NewLine,
      Enumerable.Range(0, rows)
          .Select(i => i*columns)
          .Select(i => singleLineString
             .Substring(i, Math.Min(columns, singleLineString.Length - i)))
    );
}
```

How's that for elegant?

Comment: You could use that method to wrap the last statement so that scrolling is not required anymore ;)

Comment: Probably LINQ's query syntax is also a good option because of the nested intermediate computations!?

Comment: _a bit of horizontal scrolling required_  haha ;-) you can use these line breaks if you want `\r\n`, `\r\n`, `\r\n`, `\r\n`, `\r\n`, `\r\n`, `\r\n`, `\r\n`, `\r\n` - I have plenty of them ;-P

Comment: Where is the fun in that?! :) On more serious note, for some special cases LINQ can be a viable option, but as you can see, for general case it is not very readable. I doubt query syntax can change that, since it will roughly translate into the same thing (except for first `Select` transforming into `let`). I would go for regular loop, as other answers suggested.