# Cleaning address line data sent to couriers API

Tags: c#, strings

I've developed a client library to integrate with a couriers shipping API. The courier only accepts a limited set of characters for addresses, so I've created a helper class to strip out invalid characters and optionally replace them (with for example a ?).

```
public static class StringCleaner
{
    private static readonly char[] ValidCharacters =
    {
        ' ', '#', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/',
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
        ':', '?', '@',
        'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
        'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
        '[', ']', '_', '`',
        'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
        'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
        '{', '|', '}', '~',
    };

    public static string CleanString(string stringToClean, string replacement = "")
    {
        int length = stringToClean.Length;
        var newString = new StringBuilder();
        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++)
        {
            if (ValidCharacters.Contains(stringToClean[i]))
            {
                newString.Append(stringToClean[i]);
            }
            else
            {
                newString.Append(replacement);
            }
        }

        return newString.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a hashset for O(1) lookup

Comment: If this code is to deal with addresses from non-English speaking countries (and even in UK, you have Welsh, Irish, Gaelic), replacing everything you consider invalid with a single symbol is not a great idea. For example, few years back I lived on street named Křížová, and once got a letter addressed to "K   ov  17" -- kudos to the post office for deciphering that, but I wouldn't rely on that. A better approach would be just stripping the accents -- for example ICU provides methods to perform such transformations (and more).

Answer (score 9):

First I'd think about names. Isn't `Clean()` enough for a method inside a class named `StringCleaner`? Do you need to repeat `String`?

Still in the prototype you should consider that you're iterating `char` but `replacement` is a `string`. It might be (or not) something to consider, it depends on your requirements.

More about `char` and `string`: you're iterating `char` (which is an UTF-16 *code unit*). UTF-16 is not fixed size then you're breaking for *code points* which are not encoded as a single code unit. More about Unicode: not every *character* is a single code point: you're breaking for surrogates. String might be (or not) normalized, do you need to take care about  it? One *grapheme* may be represented using two or more code points: think about, for example, `ộ` Vietnamese character. You may read [How can I perform a Unicode aware character by character comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27229590/1207195)

For now let's assume that to iterate `char` is perfectly fine. If not then read an almost ready to use example in [Split a string into chunks of the same length](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/111919/13424).

In .NET strings are immutable then reading `String.Length` in a loop is perfectly fine and compiler is capable to optimize it. You already know the *maximum* length of the string then you may preallocate the `StringBuilder` buffer to the maximum capacity:

```
var newString = new StringBuilder(stringToClean.Length);
```

`foreach` will help to make code shorter and easier to follow:

```
foreach (var c in stringToClean)
{
    if (ValidCharacters.Contains(c))
    {
        newString.Append(c);
    }
    else
    {
        newString.Append(replacement);
    }
}
```

If `replacement` can be a `char` it's even easier:

```
foreach (var c in stringToClean)
    newString.Append(ValidCharacters.Contains(c) ? c : replacement);
```

You may want to see a LINQ version (in case you find it more readable):

```
new String(stringToClean.Select(c => ValidCharacters.Contains(c) ? c : replacement));
```

## Performance

In general you should be careful with parameters with a default value, in this case also because of performance. If you add an overload for the common case then you can write:

```
public static string CleanString(string stringToClean)
    =>  new String(stringToClean.Where(ValidCharacters.Contains(c)));
```

Searching each character inside the array is something terribly slow. First approach: `HashSet<char>`. Build the list and search inside the hashed collection. It's WAY faster.

We're talking about true/false values and all valid characters are inside the 7 bit ASCII range...if performance really matters you may use a `BitVector`. Unfortunately default implementation throws `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if you ask for a value outside the assigned range; if you do not want to create a vector of 2^16/8 bytes then you may write your own implementation (see for example [Count items existing in 2 Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31070591/1207195) for a quick and dirty comparison).

Comment: I need to read like about twenty times your answers about unicode, characters and all the encoding stuff... currently I don't get anything ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t tnx, fixed! I know...it doesn't matter how hard I try...I won't ever learn how to explain things :( :( :( not even in my native language! All my respect and admiration to Teachers and Educators out there

Comment: No! Sorry, I didn't mean they are badly explained! Not at all. I meant this topic appears to be so complex to me at the moment that it'll take several readings until it starts makings sense ;-)

Comment: I didn't take it as an offence (well not even as a criticism...). That it's badly explained is what I was saying in my comment. I strongly think that if someone can't understand it at first glance then the problem is with the explanation. I think that the best explanation I saw has been written by tchrist (I don't know if he's active on CR but for sure in SO) in one blog post (or book? can't even remember)

Comment: Oh, the answers are well written but they require some additional background knowledge like reading about what are code points, grapheme, or the many other links you posted here and there (which is a great help because it saves readers a lot of searching). You simply cannot include all that in an answer so after reading the other articles you read the main one again, but this time equipped with the new knowledge.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Your `new String(stringToClean.Where(ValidCharacters.Contains(c)));` code has two compile errors: `c` should be declared in lambda, you should add `ToArray` after `Where` call because there are no string constructor with `IEnumerable<char>` overload. So final implementation should be `new String(stringToClean.Where(c => ValidCharacters.Contains(c)).ToArray());`. Also you should `ToArray()` call for line `new String(stringToClean.Select(c => ValidCharacters.Contains(c) ? c : replacement));`

Comment: Absolutely true, my bad! I'll fix when in front of a computer.

Comment: "You already know the maximum length of the string then you may preallocate the StringBuilder buffer to the maximum capacity:" this is unnecessary and won't actually speed things up

Comment: @benjamin it's pretty necessary and it does speed up things. A buffer which doesn't need to be resized (allocation + copy) is the reason we use StringBuilder instead of String. Is it a noticeable improvement? If you're processing 1000 strings made of 64 characters then it's not (but pooling the StringBuilder in that case will definitely help). If you are processing a 200 MB text file in memory then it's definitely worthy.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti you're assuming a string is an array and that the JIT isn't smart enough to figure this out on its own - it's not (an array) and it is (smart enough). Eric Lippert has a blog post about this being one of the first optimizations that they made somewhere.

Comment: I'm not strictly assuming that a string is an array but that it's immutable and that its content is stored in a contiguous memory area. StringBuilder MAY break these assumptions and store its buffer in multiple chunks (I don't know if it does or not, I assume it's an implementation detail) but you still pay a price (admittedly lower) when you call ToString(). That's the whole point: we know the maximum size, let's help it (I never ever saw this inferred by C# or JIT compilers)

Answer (score 6):

Use hashset for O(1)
String will enumerate characters

```
private static readonly HashSet<char> ValidCharacters = new HashSet<char> 
{   ' ', '#', '&', '\'', '(', ')', '+', ',', '-', '.', '/', 
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9',
    ':', '?', '@',
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
    'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',
    '[', ']', '_', '`',
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
    'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z',
    '{', '|', '}', '~',
};

public static string CleanString(string stringToClean, string replacement = "")
{
    var newString = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in stringToClean)
    {
        if (ValidCharacters.Contains(c))
        {
            newString.Append(c);
        }
        else
        {
            newString.Append(replacement);
        }
    }
    return newString.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I cannot teach you anything about encoding, like [@Adriano Repetti](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/190798/59161) did in his great answers but maybe I can save you from more typing...

You don't have to create a `char[]` yourself, `string`s are already arrays so let the compiler concatenate them and initialize the collection from a `string`:

```
new HashSet<char>(
    " #&" + 
    "01234"
);
```

Comment: I didn't even think about it! That's a great tip

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `Regex` for this.

```
public static class StringCleaner
{
    private const Pattern = @"[^a-zA-Z0-9 \#\\\'\(\)\+\,\-\.\/\[\]_`\{\|\}\~\:\?@]";

    public static string Clean(string address, string replacement = "") =>
        Regex.Replace(address, Pattern, replacement);
}
```

Comment: The special characters might look better if left as string and escaped with `Regex.Escape`, this wouldn't require that many "\", I think ;-)

Comment: @t3chb0t Unfortunately not all characters will be escaped. Tested this. For example `]` and `-` won't be escaped.

Comment: Oh, I guess I should have looked at the docs before writing it... I see it's not that useful here _Escapes a minimal set of characters_ and this is just the half of the above character list...  :-|